# Digits in product of two numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

When we multiply a $m$ digit number with a $n$ digit number, the product will have either $m+n$ digits or $m+n-1$ digits. I want to get some condition on the numbers so that we can predict about these two cases.

One straight forward condition: If the leftmost digits of the two numbers result in a number greater than $10$ on multiplication, it will fall in the first case.

I am not sure how to move forward.

Comment: Not a condition, but the probability that the product has $m+n$ digits is approximately $\frac{10(\log10-1)}{81}$ which is around $16\%$. The approximation gets better as $m$ and $n$ get larger.

Comment: @gandalf61 How did you calculate this probability?

Comment: Assume the range of numbers is continuous (this is the approximation), scale each number to be between $0$ and $9$ and the condition that the product has $m+n$ digits is $(x+1)(y+1) \le 10$. Integrate $y=\frac{10}{x+1}-1$ between $0$ and $9$ then divide this by the total area which is 81. I made a mistake above - probability is $\frac{10\log10-9}{81} \approx 17\%$.

Answer (score 2):

A positive integer has $n$ digits iff it is $\ge 10^{n-1}$ and $<10^n$, or is of the form $\alpha10^n$ with $0.1\le \alpha<1$. So if the second number id $\beta 10^m$, their product $\alpha\beta10^{n+m}$ will have $n+m$ digits iff $0.1\le \alpha\beta<1$. The $<1$ part always holds as $\alpha,\beta<1$. To decide whether $\alpha\beta\ge1$ or $\alpha\beta<0.1$, it may be sufficient to compute $\alpha\beta$ only with limited precision, i.e., to multiply only a few leading digits of the original integers.

For example, if the first factor begins with $1$, this makes $\alpha<0.2$ and we conclude that $\alpha\beta<0.1$ if $\beta\le0.5$ (i.e., leading digit $\le4$), but cannot make any prediction for leading digits $5$ to $9$: $10\cdot 90$ has three digits, but $19\cdot 59$ has four.

Another example: If you know the leading two digits of the first number are $23$, this tells you $0.23\le\alpha<0.24$. If follows that for $\alpha\beta\ge1$ it is *sufficient* that $\beta\ge 0.44$ (or that $\beta\ge 434783$, say) and *necessary* that $\beta> 0.41\overline 6$. So if the other factor has leading digit $1$ to $3$, or the leading digits are $40$ or $41$ followed by less than $6$, etc., then the product has only $n+m-1$ digits. Whereas if the leading digit is $5$ or more, or the leading digits are a $4$ followed by $4$ or more, or ..., then the product has $n+m$ digits. In the cases not covered, we simply need more information (in particular, more digits of the first number).

Comment: There's a missing decimal before $434783$ at the end of the second line of the final paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Each of those numbers can be written in scientific notation, that is, as a number ≥ and < 10 times a power of 10. As an example, let's take $41 \times 71$. So $m = 2$ and $n = 2$. Then $41 \times 71$ can be reexpressed as $(4.1 \times 10^1) \times (7.1 \times 10^1)$ which is equal to $(4.1 \times 7.1) \times 10^2$. Now $4.1 \times 7.1 = 29.11$ which is greater than or equal to 10. So $(4.1 \times 7.1) \times 10^2$ can be reexpressed as $29.11 \times 10^2$ which in scientific notation is $2.911 \times 10^3$. Since $4.1 \times 7.1$ is greater than or equal to 10, the number of digits of $41 \times 71$ is $m + n$.

Comment: This is a correct calculation but does not answer the question. The OP wants a way to decide on the number of digits without doing all the arithmetic.

Comment: @EthanBolker That's the best way I can find. I don't see a better one. All you have to do is determine whether the product of the first part of one number in scientific notation and the first part of the other number in scientific notation is greater than or equal to 10 or not. I think the author will be able to figure out from my answer that that's what I was thinking.